# Can't retrieve php cookie to keep user logged in

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to add a "stay logged in" feature on my website.

So far I have the following code:

When the user logs for the first time, I'm setting the cookie:

```
setcookie("insalata_delivery", $info['hash'], time()+(3600*24*30*12*10),'/');
```

In the index page, I check if the cookie exists and redirect the user:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["insalata_delivery"])){
$hashCookie =$_COOKIE["insalata_delivery"];
$sqlLogar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE hash='".$hashCookie."' AND active=1");
$rsLogar = mysql_fetch_array($sqlLogar);
$_SESSION['nome'] = limitWords($rsLogar['nome'],1);
$_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $rsLogar['id_usuario'];
header('Location:logged.php');
exit;}
```

I checked on firebug and I can see the cookie, but when I leave the website or open it on a new tab, it still ask me to enter my login and password instead of redirect the user by the cookie info.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

var_dump:

```
array(9) {
    ["PHPSESSID"] => string(26)
    "1214aav6r4ek9cvmm1dhq00ks1" ["ARRAffinity"] => string(64)
    "b16d3d8d62eb9ebe1c8b1163db2e1e31dca8d40ca204a5a817fb79c000a99daf" ["WAWebSiteSID"] => string(32)
    "2db406e3cf6a44ca86351062ef622dbb" ["__utmt"] => string(1)
    "1" ["insalata_delivery"] => string(15)
    "PY6Mk90kFMb2UXf" ["__utma"] => string(54)
    "82650190.1335015074.1447247171.1447247171.1447247171.1" ["__utmb"] => string(24)
    "82650190.5.10.1447247171" ["__utmc"] => string(8)
    "82650190" ["__utmz"] => string(69)
    "82650190.1447247171.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)"
}
```

**Just found something interesting: if you access the domain without the www it works, but if the user type www.domain.com, it doesn't!**

Comment: Just a side comment, it's not good to put the cookie value directly into the query. People can tamper with the cookie values and therefore it leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "Path" parameter?

Comment: If you var_dump($_COOKIE); just before this if statement, what prints out on the site? Post this var dump here...

Comment: i hope you are starting the session before setting it.

Comment: Here's the var_dump:
array(9) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "1214aav6r4ek9cvmm1dhq00ks1" ["ARRAffinity"]=> string(64) "b16d3d8d62eb9ebe1c8b1163db2e1e31dca8d40ca204a5a817fb79c000a99daf" ["WAWebSiteSID"]=> string(32) "2db406e3cf6a44ca86351062ef622dbb" ["__utmt"]=> string(1) "1" ["insalata_delivery"]=> string(15) "PY6Mk90kFMb2UXf" ["__utma"]=> string(54) "82650190.1335015074.1447247171.1447247171.1447247171.1" ["__utmb"]=> string(24) "82650190.5.10.1447247171" ["__utmc"]=> string(8) "82650190" ["__utmz"]=> string(69) "82650190.1447247171.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" }

Comment: @Bsienn: Yes I am. If I stay in the same table and open the login page, it redirect just fine. The problem is when I close the page. Looks like the cookie is gone too!

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Yes I tried. No lucky.
I'm not sure if it's a problem with my site running on https or http.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the domain in the setcookie function and it works!

```
setcookie("insalata_delivery", $info['hash'], time()+(3600*24*30*12*10),'/','mydomain.com');
```